# hibernate + jersey2 + Json + blob image

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jersey, blob

I want to be able to upload a file along with Json. I'm using hibernate and jersey2.

I already tried sending req. with postman, but nothing seems to work.
I'm getting errors like:

Can not construct instance of java.sql.Blob: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@908c4c5; line: 9, column: 28] (through reference chain: entity.Car["pictures"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->entity.Picture["image"])

Car entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "car_id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "km")
private int km;
@Column(name = "modelyear")
private int modelyear;
@Column(name = "make")
private String make;
@Column(name = "model")
private String model;
@Column(name = "motorsize", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(2,1)")
private float motorsize;
@Column(name = "motortype")
private String motortype;
@Column(name = "fueltype")
private String fueltype;
@Column(name = "price")
private int price;

@Transient
List<ResourceLink> links = new ArrayList<ResourceLink>();

@JsonProperty("pictures")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "car", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();
```

Picture entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "picture_id")
private int pictureId;

@Lob
@Column(name = "picture", columnDefinition = "mediumblob")
private Blob image;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
private Car car;
```

Hibernate imp:

```
public void create(Car entity) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(entity);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}

public Car findById(Integer id) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    Car car = session.get(Car.class, id);
    session.close();
    return car;
}
```

Car service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createCar(Car car, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    carDAO.create(car);
    BigInteger id = carDAO.findLatestId();
    URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(String.valueOf(id)).build();
    return Response.created(uri).build();
}
```